# Bind every key/click to window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I want to bind every key on the keyboard to the window so that when it is clicked it will run my method and nothing else.

I found that `root.bind_all("<Key>", MyFunction)` will bind every key. But when I press the windows key it will still open the start menu. Alt-Tab  is not stopped from changing tabs either.

Is there a keybind that covers all keys, or is their a better way to stop the client from leaving the program by force? (I used `root.attributes("-fullscreen", 1)` to make the window look 'un-exitable')

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or is their a better way to stop the client from leaving the program by force?

No. Operating systems don't allow it. Otherwise the user would have no way to leave the virus you are writing.

Operating systems evaluate the keystrokes first, and pass the relevant ones on to the program. The ones that get passed on can be caught the way you have it. Things like disabling the start menu key have to be done within the operating system settings.

That said, each OS may have hooks available. For example, [here is one for Ubuntu Unity](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/disable_super_key.py) that disables the Windows key.